# How to properly resume app

Tags: android, multithreading, surfaceview

I'm new to Android and threading.

### What app does

I have a simple app that just shows a bitmap bouncing around within the screen's boundaries (i.e. if bitmap hits the right edge of the screen, it will reverse direction).

### Issue

App freezes when I minimize it and also sometimes takes a long time to load and when it loads I see a black screen.

### QUESTION

Please try to run the code it is just one file shown below, I just use SurfaceView as layout. There is nothing advanced in term of what app does.
I'm confused as to why we need to use SurfaceHolder.Callback anonymous class (used in a method in the nested SurfaceView class) if there are life cycle methods I write called a pause, resume and stop in nested SurfaceView class that is called by the Main Activity's onPause, onResume, onStop methods. The entire code is shown followed by the structure of app to see an overview that I made because I don't see the point of SurfaceHolder.Callback methods so I mean I don't know why we need to use surfaceCreated, surfaceChanged, surfaceDestroyed and I don't know what to put in surfaceChanged. I also have an onSaveInstanceSate and onRestoreInstance state methods that just save the bitmap's x and y coordinates.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

GameView gameView;
Handler myHandler;
int xPos = 0;
int yPos = 0;
int deltaX = 3;
int deltaY = 3;
int iconWidth;
int iconHeight;

static final String STATE_POS_X = "playerPosX";
static final String STATE_POS_Y = "playerPosY";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myHandler = new Handler ();
    gameView = new GameView(this);
    setContentView(gameView);
}

class GameView extends SurfaceView {

    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private Bitmap bmpIcon;
    private MyThread myThread;

    volatile boolean playingGame = true;

    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public GameView(Context context,
                         AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public GameView(Context context,
                         AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init(){

        myThread = new MyThread(this);

        surfaceHolder = getHolder();
        bmpIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.rubberBall);

        iconWidth = bmpIcon.getWidth();
        iconHeight = bmpIcon.getHeight();

        surfaceHolder.addCallback( new SurfaceHolder.Callback(){

            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                myThread.setRunning(true);
                myThread.start();
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,
                                       int format, int width, int height) {
                // What do I enter here???

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                boolean retry = true;
                myThread.setRunning(false);
                while (retry) {
                    try {
                        myThread.join();
                        retry = false;
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            }});
    }

    protected void drawSomething(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmpIcon,
                getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2, null);

        xPos += deltaX;
        if(deltaX > 0){
            if(xPos >= getWidth() - iconWidth){
                deltaX *= -1;
            }
        }else{
            if(xPos <= 0){
                deltaX *= -1;
            }
        }

        yPos += deltaY;
        if(deltaY > 0){
            if(yPos >= getHeight() - iconHeight){
                deltaY *= -1;
            }
        }else{
            if(yPos <= 0){
                deltaY *= -1;
            }
        }

        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmpIcon,
                xPos, yPos, null);

    }

    public void pause() {
        playingGame = false;
        try {
            myThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    public void resume() {
        playingGame = true;
        myThread = new MyThread(this);
        myThread.start();
    }

}//END INNER CLASS: GameView

class MyThread extends Thread {

    GameView myView;
    private boolean running = false;

    public MyThread(GameView view) {
        myView = view;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean run) {
        running = run;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running){

            Canvas canvas = myView.getHolder().lockCanvas();

            if(canvas != null) {
                synchronized (myView.getHolder()) {
                    myView.drawSomething(canvas);
                }
                myView.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }

            try {
                this.sleep(30);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }//END WHILE
      }
}//END INNER CLASS: MyThread

/**
 * BELOW are Main Activity Life Cycle Call Back methods!
 *
 */
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d("onStop", "Main Activity's onStop called");
    while (true) {
        gameView.pause();
        break;
    }
    this.finish();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d("onResume", "Main Activity's onResume called");
    gameView.resume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d("onPause", "Main Activity's onPause called");
    gameView.pause();
}

//save and restore state
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // Save the user's current game state
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_POS_X, xPos);
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_POS_Y, yPos);
}

public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Always call the superclass so it can restore the view hierarchy
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // Restore state members from saved instance
    xPos = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_POS_X);
    yPos = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_POS_Y);
}

}//END CLASS: MainActivity
```

### STRUCTURE of MainActivity housing the nested SurfaceView class

```
MainActivity life cycle methods
--------------------------------
onCreate:
------------
-links up the layout which is the SurfaceView instance
-initialize variables

onPause:
---------
call the SurfaceView's custom pause method here in addition to calling the 
super's onPause

onStop:
------
call the SurfaceView's custom stop method here in addition to calling the 
super's onStop

onResume:
---------
call the SurfaceView's custom resume method here in addition to calling the 
super's onResume

  nested Thread class
  ------------------------
  run method to run SurfaceView

  nested class SurfaceView's life cycle methods
  -------------------------------------------------------
    pause method which pauses the worker thread 
    ---------------------------------------------
    stop the worker thread:

    stop method which stops the worker thread:
    -----------------------------------------
    stop the worker thread

    resume method which creates a new worker thread:
    ---------------------------------------------------
    make a new worker thread

    SurfaceHolder.Callback lifespan methods
    ***Why do we need to write the methods below if I have pause,
    resume stop already that will be called by the Main Activity's
    onXXX, respectively????
    ==========================================

    surfaceCreated:
    ---------------
    make a new worker thread

    surfaceChanged:
    ---------------
     What do I enter here??

    surfaceDestroyed:
    -----------------
    destroy current worker thread

    END of nested SurfaceView class

override onSaveInstanceState method:
------------------------------------
save the bitmap's position (x and y coordinates)

override onRestoreInstanceState method:
-----------------------------------------
restore the bitmap's position (x and y coordinates)

END of MainActivity
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the very well explanation because SurfaceView is more fine tuned control of graphics unlike drawing with a Custom View or using predefined graphical inputs or GUI elems.

http://blog.infrared5.com/2011/07/android-graphics-and-animation-part-ii-animation/